# WPF application TypeInitializationException when run on another machine

Tags: wpf, exception

I have a complicated WPF application that references a few other projects.  It runs fine on my development machine, actually works great.  Then, when I port it over to another machine running the same OS and .Net version - it complains of a TypeInitializationException in one of the libraries.  I've tried everything to no avail.  One thing I noticed is that the library referenced in the error message uses the Shell32 Interop - as does the main program (don't ask why, ok, it's for Android access) - the error message is "An item with the same key has already been added" - even though I don't get that error on my development machine - I'm thinking perhaps it's loading two Shell32's and getting confused?  I'm at my wit's end, investigated every app.config setting, even installed the latest version of .net.  Ideally, I'd be able to duplicate the error on the development machine, but so far, can't!

Comment: Please post the relevant exception message and stack trace.

Comment: This has been resolved by rebuilding/updating the NuGet packages